# how to add multiple non continuous lines with x-as overlap in a mschart

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, plot, mschart

I'n not really familiar with ms chart and have been googleing throughout the day to find an example of what I need, but was not able to find it.

I would like to be able to plot multiple lines on a chart like this:

[image]

(this is done manually, just to make clear what I need).

I can calculate each value the line has per x value per line. I store it in a list which hold the DateAndValue object:

```
[Serializable]
public struct DateAndValue
{
    public uint DBDate { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int BarNumber { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, it's not really possible to use one list for support lines and one for resistance, because there might be multiple lines of the same sort (i.e. support) in the same period.

What would be a good way of storing (must be update-able) the data and plot it in the chart, without having zero values when there is no data.

I could also make an object that only contains start and end point per line. In that case I would just update the end value if necessary.

Suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Kind regards,

Matthijs

Comment: Have you managed do add line in you candlestick chart?

Answer (score 1):

Not so long ago i asked a question on stack overflow on how to create a candlestick chart, the answer and my question together shoud lead u in the right direction

here is the url:

[candlestick-multiple-y-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983199/candlestick-multiple-y-values)

How to make trendlines in your chart? my guess is that u can add a new serie for each line with 2 points (maybe by selecting 2 different candles), and normally you can fill in the "missing" points between your 2 points with a solid line, dotted line etc..

I hope somebody more experienced than me can give u a better answer!